# Loading OS onto laptop via PXE

Tags: pxe

I have an old Lenovo Edge 15 80H1 which (long story short) has no OS installed. I want to rescue the machine, but I can't boot from a usb because none of the usb ports work. It also doesn't recognize a bootable SD card, so (to my knowledge) the only way to get an OS onto it is with PXE. I am clueless about how PXE works, so I'm hoping to get help using it.

Ideally I would load it with linux mint, but I'll settle for whatever I have to do to get it working.

Comment: You need a DHCP server, a tftp server and an http server. Their configuration is a bit too complex for an answer in Superuser.com, but numerous tutorials are available online.

Comment: I believe Clonezilla offers an all-in-one solution for an image server and PXE boot.

Comment: Ubuntu has some [official documentation on setting up a basic netboot server](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64). [This tool](https://github.com/dannf/ubuntu-server-netboot) also looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's too much to cover in a single post, but [NetworkBoot.org](https://networkboot.org/) is a great resource to get you started.

You'll need a TFTP server to serve the bootloader and a properly configured DHCP server to point the PXE firmware to boot files on that TFTP server. Then you'll probably want to boot [iPXE](https://ipxe.org) first, which is a more powerful PXE firmware replacement. Finally, you can use iPXE to boot any ISO over HTTP(S) (something plain PXE can't do).

Unfortunately PXE is finicky, at least on consumer hardware that I've tried to use it with. You can for example hit device-specific file size limitations. Going with a netboot ISO may be a good idea.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment what's wrong with this answer and how it should be improved. Otherwise it will stay wrong forever.

Comment: Booting a ISO directly often fails, but depends on how it is built.
The best way is to extract kernel and initrd and chain that in iPXE, a quick example at http://boot.ipxe.org/demo

images using squashfs often requires some extra work, but a great resource on what works with what is https://netboot.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

To set up a Serva PXE server you just need a single 4 MB exe file.

see here:

[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/default.html](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/default.html)

for basics on PXE you can read:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment